# How to set the library suffix on CMake for SOCI?

Tags: c++, cmake, soci

I am trying to build SOCI on Windows with a different library suffix using the `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` option, but the script seems to ignore it.

Here is the command I run in a batch file:

```
cmake^
 -G "NMake Makefiles"^
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release^
 -DCMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX="-vc140-x64-mt.dll"^
 ..\soci.3.2.3
```

The [documentation](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/installation.html#windows) does not say anything about the `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` option, but the `core/CMakeLists.txt` script uses it to define the `SOCI_LIB_SUFFIX` option, which is reported on the screen when `cmake` is run. However, its value is always `".dll"` instead of `"-vc140-x64-mt.dll"`, so it must be overwritten somewhere I don't know.

Any idea why is this happening and how fix it?

Comment: Looks like SOCI changes variable `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` for its own purposes. You may find this usage (e.g. with help of command [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/variable_watch.html) at the beginning of the script) and modify it as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your comment gave me insights and I could find the problem and a solution. But the problem is more related to CMake than SOCI. So I think I should rewrite the question to use SOCI just as an example project. After that I could post a more suitable answer.